# Can I configure Apache by providing additional configuration files (and not touching the ones installed by default)?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I'm configuring Apache under a Debian based Linux distribution.   I would like to configure it in such a way that my configuration changes don't get in the way of Apache upgrades.  I would like to do it in such a way that I don't have to edit any of the configuration files that come with the distribution.

I know that I can put the configuration for my websites in the */etc/apache2/sites-available* directory and then enable them with `a2ensite`.  Similarly, I can enable the modules I want with `a2enmod`.

What happens if I write new configuration files into */etc/apache2/conf-available/* and then use `a2enconf` to enable them?   Specifically, will the be able to override settings that are specified in other configuration files.   For example */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* specifies `Timeout 300`.  If I put `Timeout 500` in my configuration file, will it override the earlier declaration?   Would there be any Apache configuration directives for which using this override technique would not work?

Comment: Just a sidenote: everything you're talking about is Debian's custom system for configuring Apache. None of that *stuff* is part of the official software. The official software just comes with a single, easy to read configuration file that doesn't need any special modifications between versions (except maybe adding new directives to enable new functionality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an encouraging answer from Kondybas, I went ahead and experimented with this.  I only ran into two problems:

1. The `Listen` directive cannot be "overridden".  By its very nature it is an "additive" directive.   What stumped my for a while was that it can't even be specified twice for the same port number.  The following will cause an error stating that port 80 is already in use and Apache cannot be started.   The solution for me was to remove the `Listen` directive from my own config and rely only on the one provided by the distribution.

   ```
   Listen 80
   Listen 80
   ```
2. The `PidFile` directive cannot be overridden on a Debian based system without also modifying the `/etc/apache2/envvars` config file.  The process id file must match between that config file and the Apache config file or Apache will not start using Debian's `service` command.

Other than that, all the other directives that I have tried work fine in a config file that specifies them a second time.

Answer (score 3):

If current configuration uses inclusion from certain directory by mask - yes, you can.

Usually that looks like that:

```
Include etc/apache22/Includes/*.conf
```

So you just copy your configuration in that directory and keep in mind that apache include includes in the lexical order. If you want to override some values already set, just name your file zzzzzzzzz.conf